# Update statement taking too long (7 minutes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, execution-time, sql-execution-plan

This is SQL code im running on SSMS 2008 R2.  It's taking over 10 minutes to run (it runs against 90,000 records)..

I'm trying to update all unique records in #tmp_hic_final where [Claim Adjustment Type Code] is 0 and [Claim Type Code] is not 10.  I'm also doing the update based on the select subquery which checks to make sure there isn't another record that has a [Claim Adjustment Type Code] of 1 in the table.

Although I don't know much on analyzing it, here's the execution plan: http://snag.gy/TLRsZ.jpg

is there a better way to optimize it?

```
update  PAHT
set [Marked Final] = 'Y'
from #tmp_hic_final PAHT
join
(
    select [HIC #],
                [Claim Type Code] , 
                [Provider Oscar #], 
                [Claim From Date] ,
                 [Claim Thru Date]
    from #tmp_hic_final
    where [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = 0
    and [Claim Type Code] <> 10
    group by [HIC #],
                [Claim Type Code] , 
                [Provider Oscar #], 
                [Claim From Date] ,
                [Claim Thru Date] 
                --,[Claim Adjustment Type Code]
    having count(*) = 1
) as PAHT_2
on PAHT.[HIC #] = PAHT_2.[HIC #] and
                                        PAHT.[Claim Type Code] = PAHT_2.[Claim Type Code] and 
                                        PAHT.[Provider Oscar #] = PAHT_2.[Provider Oscar #] and
                                        PAHT.[Claim From Date] = PAHT_2.[Claim From Date]  and
                                        PAHT.[Claim Thru Date] = PAHT_2.[Claim Thru Date] 

where PAHT.[Claim Adjustment Type Code] = 0
and PAHT.[Claim Type Code] <> 10
and NOT EXISTS (select 
                    [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
                from [ACO].[dbo].[PA_Header_Temp]
                where 
                    [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                    and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                    and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                    and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                    and [Claim Thru Date] = PAHT.[Claim Thru Date]
                    and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  = 1)
```

Table definition and index on PA_Header_Temp:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].['PA_Header']    Script Date: 06/02/2015 2:32:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PA_Header_Temp](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Current ClaimID] [float] NULL,
    [Provider OSCAR #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [HIC #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Type Code] [float] NULL,
    [Claim From Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Claim Thru Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Claim Bill Facility Type Code] [float] NULL,
    [Claim Bill Classification Code] [float] NULL,
    [Principal Diagnosis Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Admitting Diagnosis Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Medicare Non Payment Reason Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Payment Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Claim NCH Primary Payer Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FIPS state Code] [float] NULL,
    [Bene Patient Status Code] [float] NULL,
    [Diagnosis Related Group Code] [float] NULL,
    [Claim Outpatient Service Type Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Facility Provider NPI #] [float] NULL,
    [Operating Provider NPI #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Attending provider NPI #] [float] NULL,
    [Other Provider NPI #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Adjustment Type Code] [float] NULL,
    [Claim Effective Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Claim IDR Load Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Bene Equitable BIC HICN #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Admission Type Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Admission Source Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Bill Frequency Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Claim Query Code] [float] NULL,
    [Marked Final] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Load Date] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: estimately how many rows are updated?

Comment: @Mino, (72658 row(s) affected) out of 90163 total.

Comment: well it updates almost all the rows. Have you thought another aspect to approach this problem. Could you update all rows to something and update those ~18k with simpler query?

Comment: @Mino, This is a good idea, but i have about 2k more lines of code prior to this piece shown that manipulates the data so I don't know if it's possible due to time constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this approach from both a readability and performance standpoint.

```
update yourTable
set field2 = someValue
where whatever
and field1 in 
(select field1
from yourTable
where whatever
except
select field1
from yourTable
where whatever
and somethingElse)
```

`where whatever` should be the same every time.

Comment: I'm too inexperienced w sql i think to fully comprehend your answer

Comment: Here is a reference.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx.  Bear in mind that they use left and right as if the query was written all on one line.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would check is indexes in the tables (normal and temp.). Especially the clustered index scan of PA_Header_Temp in the nested loop looks really bad. Depending on the columns and data (data types, selectivity, row count) you should probably create index with either some or all of the columns, either as normal or included fields.

It might be a good idea to create clustered indexes for the temp. tables too, probably on the columns used for joining and for #tmp_hic_final you should also consider the fields used as where criteria in the update.

Edit: Have you tried populating PAHT_2 into a separate temp. table before running the update (+ indexing it) -- that might help too.

Comment: Added temp table to see if this helps any

Comment: Didn't do much with making it a temp table.  I think my PA_Header_Temp table already has a clustered index fyi

Comment: Do the fields in Pa_Header_Temp match the query? You probably should include the table definitions (at least the important parts) and indexes to the question.

Comment: added definition to question

Comment: If the ID is the only indexed field, that's something to improve, maybe [Provider OSCAR #] or [HIC #] if those are unique (or at least not many rows per each one) and if the key lookups cause a lot of I/O, adding other fields to the index as include fields might help.

Answer (score 0):

So, I took ther advice of @Dan Bracuk and converted my code using his format and it knocked down my execution time from 6:57 to 2:30 (if my math is right thats a 65% increase in performance)

```
update PAHT  
set PAHT.[Marked Final] = 'Y'
from #tmp_hic_final PAHT
where [Claim Adjustment Type Code] = 0
    and [Claim Type Code] <> 10
and [Claim Adjustment Type Code] in 
(select 
                    [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
                from [ACO].[dbo].[PA_Header_Temp]
                where 
                    [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                    and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                    and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                    and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                    and [Claim Thru Date] = PAHT.[Claim Thru Date]
except
select 
                    [Claim Adjustment Type Code] 
                from [ACO].[dbo].[PA_Header_Temp]
                where 
                    [HIC #] = PAHT.[HIC #]
                    and [Provider Oscar #] = PAHT.[Provider Oscar #]
                    and [Claim Type Code] = PAHT.[Claim Type Code]
                    and [Claim From Date] = PAHT.[Claim From Date]
                    and [Claim Thru Date] = PAHT.[Claim Thru Date]
                    and [Claim Adjustment Type Code]  = 1)
```

Comment: Add an index on [HIC #] and watch your time shrink to 1/500th that :)

Comment: @Ghost, on only HIC # ?

Comment: What field to index depends on selectivity (how many rows per a key), and datatypes too, since those are nvarchar(255)s, the index might be quite huge if the data is that long.

Comment: @tshoemake [PA_Header_Temp] should be indexed on it as well as the temp table. As with all things SQL, test and verify. JamesZ is right as well, the index might be quite large, but it probably is worth it.